# freezed package class return - "type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast"

Tags: flutter, dart, oop, typeclass, flutter-freezed

I am new to Dart and OOP. I am using freezed package to create my Model classes. I cant get the response to return in my function, always goes to catch(error)

here is my code

```
static Future<SearchResponse?> searchImageBasedCatagory(
  File file,
  {requiresToken = true}) async {
try {
  String fileExtension = p.extension(file.path);
  List<String> finalExtension = fileExtension.split('.');
  var formData = FormData.fromMap({
    'searchImage': await MultipartFile.fromFile(
      file.path,
      contentType: MediaType("image", finalExtension[1]),
    ),
  });
  var res = await NetworkCommon.dio.post(
    EndPoints.imageBasedSearch,

    options: Options(
      headers: {'requires_token': true},
    ),
    data: formData,
  );
  var response = SearchResponse.fromJson(res.data);
  return response;
} catch (error) {
  return null;
 }
}
```

My models

SearchResponse

```
@freezed
 class SearchResponse with _$SearchResponse {
   factory SearchResponse({
     required String message,
     required int length,
     required List<CameraImageCatagoryItem> data,
}) = _SearchResponse;

 factory SearchResponse.fromJson( Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
  _$SearchResponseFromJson(json);
}
```

CameraImageCatagoryItem

```
@freezed
class CameraImageCatagoryItem with _$CameraImageCatagoryItem {
  factory CameraImageCatagoryItem(
  {
    int? width,
    int? height,
    required List<BoundBoxItem> boundBox}) = _CameraImageCatagoryItem;

  factory CameraImageCatagoryItem.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$CameraImageCatagoryItemFromJson(json);
}
```

BoundBoxItem

```
@freezed
class BoundBoxItem with _$BoundBoxItem {
   factory BoundBoxItem({
     required String catagory,
     int? prob,
     int? area,
     required List<int> bound_box,
     List<int>? expand_by_bound_box,
     required String gender
}) = _BoundBoxItem;

  factory BoundBoxItem.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
       _$BoundBoxItemFromJson(json);
}
```

Data Sample

```
 {
"message": "success",
"length": 1,
"data": [
    {
        "width": 299,
        "height": 514,
        "boundBox": [
            {
                "category": "t-shirts",
                "prob": 0.9578810930252075,
                "area": 0.5919081764116445,
                "bound_box": [
                    25,
                    139,
                    299,
                    471
                ],
                "expand_by_bound_box": [
                    0,
                    106,
                    298,
                    504
                ],
                "gender": "men"
            }
        ]
    }
]
 }
```

The code always end in error block and message is always
type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast

[image]

Comment: Can you provide more information like console output or stack trace track? i cant find out which line caused this error

Answer (score 1):

There are some problems in this code:

```dart
factory BoundBoxItem({
  required String catagory,
  int? prob,
  int? area,
  // ...
}) = _BoundBoxItem;
```

1. You named the parameter `catagory` (4th letter is 'a'), but in the data JSON it's `category` (4th letter is 'e').
2. You give `prob` and `area` the type of `int`, but in the JSON it's a `double`. Consider using [`num`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/num-class.html) to handle both `int` and `double`.

Comment: omg, thanks man. this is working now. I cant believe this, it's always a typo lol

Comment: I noticed you also have the same typo in the class name (`CameraImageCatagoryItem`). You can use the [Code Spell Checker](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=streetsidesoftware.code-spell-checker) extension to detect typos